# Earthing a gate motor

Tags: electrical, grounding, electric-motor, gates

I'm installing a gate motor for out front gate and I'm trying to figure out the best way to install the earth connection. The operator itself comes with a ground wire that's attached to the housing, but it's not connected to the PCB. The PCB itself has a connector for L, N and PE. Here are some photos:

[image]

The instructions are vague and the diagram indicates two earth cables mounted to the housing. Does anyone know why there're two earth cables? What's the best way to install the earth connection? How about using a wire nut like this:

[image]

Is this "separating power cables from control and safety cables"? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm in the UK

Comment: Why do you think it is unusual for there to be separate wires from the PE on the PCB and motor? This is quite common and even required in many cases on my side of the pond.